# Broken laptop external monitor not working after uninstalling graphics driver

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

Okay, my laptop screen had broke and I had been using an external monitor for a while. One day I foolishly uninstalled the graphics drivers because one of my games wasn't working properly. When I went to boot up my laptop the external display stopped functioning. I've tried unplugging the laptops internal display, closing the lid with the external display plugged in, using a windows install disk (but since I'm doing this without display I don't get very far as I don't have another computer/laptop to follow along with.) I'm lost at what to do and I'm struggling with money so I'm iffy on purchasing a new lcd screen in case that doesn't work because I would be out 100$ that I can't afford to risk if it doesn't work. Can anyone suggest anything? Pressing fn keys to bring up the other display is a no go as the key on the keyboard to do that is also broken.

Comment: So you dont get ANY output at all on the external monitor when you boot the laptop?   I would assume you would see the inital BIOS post screen, and then it would stop displaying as soon as the OS loads.   Is this the case?   If so I may have a fix for you.

Comment: If you have RDP enabled you can try remote access to your laptop and try to change display settings.

Comment: I was thinking of that as well, but she said she does not have another laptop/computer available, so she would not have a way to connect via RDP.

Comment: Broken LCD, broken keys, fear of repairs - sounds like it might just be time for a new laptop... :)

Comment: No bios screen, nothing. I'm unsure if RDP is enabled or not. I do have another computer but it's windows 10 and my laptop is windows 7 so it's a completely different setup.

Comment: I dont fear repairing it I just fear wasting the money and having it not work seeing as I'm in a financial struggle at the moment I can't really afford to waste 100$ just to find out it didn't help.

Comment: Is the screen on your laptop totally non functional (no display at all) or is it just not optimal for daily use?   My suggestion was going to be press and hold F6 on the keyboard and try to boot into safe mode.  Safe mode loads windows without all of the drivers and other crap you have installed and will give you access to your desktop.   There is even a mode that will allow networking in safe mode, so that way you can download the driver from whatever company made your video card.

Comment: The strange part is, uninstalling your video card driver should not have eliminated the ability to display video.   Usually windows would revert to a generic VGA driver if you were to uninstall your graphics drivers.   Also, the driver does not actually get called on until Windows boots, so the fact that you are not seeing any output at all when you start the computer up is troubling.   What make/model of laptop do you own (the one with the video problem)?